# A Fatal Error Occurred While Creating An Ssl Server Credential when connect to WCF RESTfull service

Tags: c#, ssl, wcf, ssl-certificate

I get an event with message "A Fatal Error Occurred While Creating An Ssl Server Credential"
when try to use WCF RESTfull service on XP. On Windows 7 and windows server 2008 all works fine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

IIS 6 and IIS 7 credential versions would be where I would start looking.